# Why does changes in nfolds change the model output of cv.glmnet?

Tags: r, logistic, cross-validation, glmnet

I have a large dataset consisting of snow (1) vs no snow (0) in pixels over a whole year, *N* = 501,126. I want to compare the two groups and predict why snow melts at a given time. So I decided to use `cv.glmnet` in R. The data is very imbalanced 500,000, 0's (no snow) to a 500 1's (snow) with 9 independent variables.

I split the data into training and testing (75 to 25 %). And use the `cv.glmnet` function with a fixed `nfolds` and `foldid`. However, as I lower the `nfolds` from `10` to `5`, my results change drastically.

When I use `nfolds = 5` I get an AUC of 0.7, when I use `nfolds = 10` the result is AUC = 0.5. It should not matter so much when dealing with datasets of +500,000 datapoints, right?

```
nfolds    5        10
AUC     0.7       0.5
```

Why do fewer fold cross-validations increase the predictive power of the model?
Is the model eventually not robust at all?

Here is my script:

```
library(readr)
Snow <- read_csv("Path/Snowmelt.csv")
View(sm)
set.seed(123)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(glmnet)
library(ROCR)
library(pROC)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(4, cores = 4)

#Train:test
training.samples <- sm$snowOccurence %>% createDataPartition(p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
train <- sm[training.samples, ]
test <- sm[-training.samples, ]
x.train <- data.frame(train[, names(train) != "fire"])
x.train <- data.matrix(x.train)
y.train <- train$fire
x.test <- data.frame(test[, names(test) != "fire"])
x.test <- data.matrix(x.test)
y.test <- test$fire
nFolds = 10 #this is also changed to 5, when using a 5-fold cross-validation
foldid = sample(rep(seq(nFolds), length.out = nrow(train)))


Snow <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, type.measure = "dev", alpha = 0, family = "binomial", nfolds = nFolds, foldid = foldid, parallel = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)
coef <- coef(Snow, s = Snow$lambda.1se)
coef

predicted <- predict(Snow, s = Snow$lambda.1se, newx = x.test, type = 'response')
pred <- prediction(predicted, y.test)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "for")
auc_ROCR <- performance(pred, measure = "auc")
auc_ROCR <- auc_ROCR@y.values[[1]]
auc_ROCR
```

Comment: Work through the arithmetic. How many 1s are held out when you use 10 folds? When you use 5 folds?

Comment: From the train data, I have something like 400 1's. So with a 10-fold CV, I will have 40 1's per group. With a 5 fold, I will have 80 per group. Is this what you mean? And, what implications does that have?

Comment: When you have imbalanced data for classification, you're really depending much more on the minority class than you are the majority class, so going from 80 to 40 examples is a really steep drop-off. By contrast, losing 40 samples from the majority class would not meaningfully influence your results.

Comment: That is true, so you would highly recommend in this case to use the 5-fold CV since the data is so imbalanced? I am just surprised that it changes the outcome relatively much. Does it also mean the model is not so robust?